# Control like ListBox but has buttons to move up and down the list

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am looking for a control that looks like a `TextBox` with an up and down button on the right hand side. As you click the buttons it should change the index of the selected item in the list. It should only show one item at a time. Hopefully this picture will better articulate what I am looking for:

[image: TextBox with up and down button to move through the list of items]

I was hoping there was a way to style a `ListBox` or `ComboBox` to pull this off, but that does not seem possible. I considered using a slider, but my list of values may or may not have gaps, (i.e. it could be 150, 151,153,160,...).

I can get close with a `ListBox` by setting the height, but it does not change the SelectedIndex as you scroll:

```
<ListBox Height="23" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
  <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

**So is there away to hook into the scroll buttons so that when the buttons are clicked I can adjust the index appropriately?** A secondary question would be, is there away to set the number of items to display in a `ListBox' before the scroll bars are added, instead of setting the height?

Comment: Do you need Text Input capabilities? I mean can the user type the number with the keyboard? If so, what happens if they type an invalid number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WinForms, there's a control for this purpose:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx

For WPF, you may consider this one:

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown&referringTitle=Home

Comment: That is close, and may be what I have to do. The issue is that I may have gaps in the values, and you can only set the maximum and minimum values for that control and how much to increment/decrement each time.

Comment: As @arifnpm mentions below, you should be able to perform some kind of validation by capturing the ValueChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use NumericUpDown control instead. and change the list index on ValueChanged event.

Comment: That is close, and may be what I have to do. The issue is that I may have gaps in the values, and you can only set the maximum and minimum values for that control and how much to increment/decrement each time.

Comment: again you can mimic the gap by put some validation in ValueChanged event to skip the gap to the next number. Increment/decrement value can be changed in the "Increment" property.